# (check(k.ToString() == 1))

Tags: c#

I have a maybe simple problem. When i start program it show "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'. I dont know what to do with it. Thanks for every help.
Here is code:

```
    class Program

{


    static bool check(string input_number)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < input_number.Length / 2; i++)
            if (input_number[i] != input_number[input_number.Length - i - 1])
                return false;
        return true;
    }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var results = from i in Enumerable.Range(100, 900)
                      from j in Enumerable.Range(i, 1000 - i)
                      let k = i * j
                      where (check(k.ToString() == 1)
                 orderby k descending
                      select new { i, j, k };
        var highestResult = results.FirstOrDefault();

        if (highestResult == null)
            Console.WriteLine("There are no palindromes!");
        else
            Console.WriteLine($"The highest palindrome is {highestResult.i} * {highestResult.j} = {highestResult.k}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you explain what you're trying to achieve? Your `check` method just accepts a string, and returns a bool... what are you trying to compare with the integer 1?

Comment: Why are you calling `ToString()` on `k`?

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking about. I guess @Damien_The_Unbeliever comment is what you need, if not  please edit de question

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare strings (`k.ToString()` with numbers (`1`). In your case, I think, you need to do this: `where check(k.ToString()) == true)`.

Comment: ....or just `where check(k.ToString())`....

Comment: @ZoharPeled; Indeed. I just wanted to keep track of the `1`, which I think, is the OP's way of checking for true values, similar to `C++` or `C`.

Comment: What's with the `== true`? What is the use?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: As mentioned in my previous comment, I kept it so as to avoid confusion by the OP as to 'where did the 1 go`. In this case, I am making an assumption that the `1` equates to true. Other than that, the `== true` has no real value, and for this specific case, can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare a string and an int directly, due to C#'s strong typing. Instead, you should "convert" the int to a string, using [ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2).

edit: or just not call `ToString` on k?

Comment: `Int32.Parse` turns a `string` into an `int`, precisely the opposite of what you just said they should do.

Comment: You are right. Edited.